# Diagonal of a Rectangle

Tags: geometry, formal-proofs, pythagorean-triples

The Pythagoreans proved that the length of the diagonal of a square with side length 1 is not a rational number. Prove that the length of the diagonal of a rectangle with sides length 1 and 2 is not a rational number.
When trying this problem, I did the pythagorean theorem. I think that is too simple.

Comment: well, after the theorem you should prove that what you obtain is not rational. How do you do that?

Comment: I would prove it by contradiction just like the square root of 3 is done all the time.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. For a rectangle with sides of length $1$ and $2$, the Pythagorean theorem states that the diagonal of that rectangle is $\sqrt {1^2+2^2}=\sqrt 5$. Since $\sqrt 5$ is a real number that cannot be expressed as a ratio of two integers where the dominator is nonzero, the diagonal of this rectangle is an  irrational number.